# Hyperledger Fabric error when I try to do ./network.sh up in test-network directory

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, private-network

**This is the error that I am getting**

Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... error
ERROR: for peer0.org1.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org1.example.com: status code not OK but 500: \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
FDocker.Core, Version=2.4.0.48506, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null                                                                                     Docker.Core.DockerException
ClassNameMeWatsonBucketsSystem.Collections.IDictionarySystem.ExceptionaceStringRemoteStackIndexExceptionMethodHResultSource
Docker.Core.DockerExceptionFilesharing has been cancelled

**I think the docker is doing some issue. Can any expert please help me out**

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. I think I have found the solution.

The problem was that I didn't mount the directory of fabric-samples. (sorry for my bad English, I am too much excited.). I was trying to work without it..

**Here's what you have to do:**

Go to docker Settings > Resources > File Sharing > Then add path to your fabric samples directory.

This will solve the problem.